# JQuery $.post() doesn't work

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-post

Can any one help me with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_user").submit(function() {
        $.post( "../php/register_sql_ins.php",
            {r_fname: $("#fname").val(),
            r_lname: $("#lname").val(),
            r_uname: $("#uname").val(),
            r_pass: $("#pass").val(),
            r_authLevel: $("#authLevel").val(),
            r_email: $("#email").val(),
            r_company: $("#company").val(),
            r_phone: $("#phone").val(),
            r_address: $("#add").val()}, function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            );
            return false;
    });
});
```

This should store my user data in a sql table. the php part of code(register_sql_ins.php) works fine. but this query piece of code just doesn't work!! and I have no idea what is the problem! 
With Firebug it returns false every time!
By the way sorry for bad english. It's not my mother tong!

Comment: If the success handler is getting called with result as false that means its make a ajax call. What is the error?

Comment: Is the PHP code being called?  What is the PHP code returning?  What is `returning false every time`?

Comment: A good place to start is examining the _Console_ in your browser (I suggest using Chrome or Firefox with Firebug add-on) since that will show exactly which URL is being called, along with the POST parameters and the response from the server

Comment: May it be that it returns false because of `return false;` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places where I would look for the cause of such error:

- `Network` tab in Firebug. Check what is sent to the server and what is the response. If data sent is correct and server replies with status 200, then you have to debug your PHP script, else
- Server logs. If the request failed to complete succesfully, log will contain the reason.